# SQL Server 2008 DB recovery: does it actually work?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Today I have rebooted my Win2008 Server with SQL Server 2008 running on it. After rebooting SQL Server marked my database as "In recovery", so I can't use this database until recovering finished. The question is - how much dose it takes to finish recovery process and does it actually do the recovery (or SQL Server just lock my db and nothing gonna happens)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it works (for example, cluster failover relies on it).

However, it could be slow for many reasons.

First, refresh SSMS/check SQL error log to see if it has complted

Second, read these while you wait...

- Still applies, [KB 820835](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820835)
- From the [MS CSS engineers](http://blogs.msdn.com/psssql/archive/2008/09/12/sql-server-2000-2005-2008-recovery-rollback-taking-longer-than-expected.aspx)
- [Paul Randall's](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/) "In recovery" blog (can't get in to refine it)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you have a database that was being restored and that process wasn't finished. Try doing the following:

RESTORE DATABASE mydb WITH RECOVERY

(that's the entire command - no other options needed)